# Issues running python on MacOS Monterey (12.1)

Tags: macos, crash, apple-silicon, monterey

While installing my project related dependencies I always get this error (refer to the image attached below). I am not sure what this is about and how to fix it. Also, I am not able to install most of my project related dependencies not sure if this is because of this issue.

However, my machine 2021 Macbook Pro with M1 Pro chip was working just fine until I updated it to MacOS Monterey (12.1). I bought this machine with MacOS Monterey installed init so I believe I cannot even rollback to Big Sur.

I did everything to fix this crash like reinstalling the MacOS via bootable drive or via internet recovery mode. But nothing has worked out.

Additionally, I have also been seeing this "Volume Hash Mismatch" notification on my machine quite frequently and my applications like Docker, PyCharm, VSCode crashes every 10 mins.

[image]

Application crash images -

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Error while reinstalling the MacOS Monterey -

[image]

Issues While reinstalling via bootable installer -

[image]

Comment: The hash mismatch/installer damage problem seems to be more severe than the Python issue, recommend to focus the question on that.

Comment: Is disk3s1 the internal SSD? Where did you get the installer from? Did you try to reinstall via Recovery mode as well?

Comment: I downloaded the installer from App store. I tried downloading OS from Recovery mode as well. but didn't work

Comment: The SSD may have a problem, maybe somebody (Apple Store) needs to have a look at it.

Comment: Have you tried running first aid (preferably in recovery mode) in disk utility? You could go about erasing the drive (**make sure to backup your data first**) and then reinstall.

Comment: I erased Macintosh HD and then from recovery mode I ran first aid. Now I don't have OS in my machine.

Comment: Well, you have to reinstall of course.

Comment: The problem was with my RAM I had to change the entire motherboard as the RAM is soldered into the board. It working fine now.